# Memory is increasing tremendously on a particular viewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, optimization

I've a view controller consisting: 
mapView, tableView, imageView(3), scrollView, 10 Labels and 3 buttons.

App Memory goes from 45MB to 85MB with the interval of 10MB. 
(Like: 45+10+10+10+10 = 85MB)

I have applied @autorelease on every secondary thread and every subViews is selected opaque.

After a lot of R&D I'm not able to optimise the memory.

I have even checked with Instruments tool for the memory leaks.

[image: here is the screenShot]

Comment: Have you tried to profile on real device not simulator? `mapView` can consume a lot of memory...

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Tell us how you fit that myriad views on the screen and what they contain in detail

Comment: @Evgeny I have tried it on real devices and I haven't allocated the MapView yet in coding.

Comment: @Teja How to Optimise the memory

Comment: @AnuragSharma have you tried to profile? It can show you the memory leaks...

Comment: WIthout seeing the code, there is no way we could suggest the ways to help you. TableView, mapView, images all leads to heavy memory consumption unless you do it in right way, Pls add code and update ur question.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan I have already tried that and mentioned in my question. Will you tell me the way of memory optimisation in this case?

Comment: @AnuragSharma with the help of `Instruments` you can profile app memory usage, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CommonMemoryProblems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH91-SW1

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  I have checked it even after commenting a lot of lines of coding such as tableView implementation.

Comment: don't you guys have any idea about this ?? Because it looks totally unusual even using Instrument tool !